# Reading in CSV into R but yield 0 observations

Tags: r, csv, file-read

I have data that looks like this, below is a screenshot from notepad. 
[image]

However, when I run the following code to read it into R, I get this.

```
pdata = read_csv('kd30.csv')
```

[image]

I think it has something to do with the " in the 12" soil moisture, because when I manually change the name to just soil12, it reads in. But I need it to work for the given column names because I have lots of data like this that needs to be read in.

Here is a sample of the data in plain text format data

```
,12" Soil Moisture (%VWC),16" Soil Moisture (%VWC),20" Soil Moisture (%VWC),Pressure Switch (on|off)
04/25/19 00:15:00,,,,0
04/25/19 00:15:06,36.4465,35.6766,36.3512,
04/25/19 00:30:00,,,,0
04/25/19 00:30:06,36.4522,35.6886,36.3581,
04/25/19 00:45:00,,,,0
04/25/19 00:45:06,36.435,35.6886,36.3581,
04/25/19 01:00:00,,,,0
04/25/19 01:00:06,36.4522,35.6826,36.3581,
04/25/19 01:15:00,,,,0
04/25/19 01:15:06,36.4177,35.6706,36.3649,
04/25/19 01:30:00,,,,0
04/25/19 01:30:05,36.4005,35.6826,36.3649,
04/25/19 01:45:00,,,,0
04/25/19 01:45:06,36.3948,35.6886,36.3717,
04/25/19 02:00:00,,,,0
04/25/19 02:00:06,36.3775,35.6947,36.3717,
```

Comment: Yes, the issue is probably due to the " which presumably means inches, but is interpreted as quotes. But please provide data in a plain text format, not as images, so as users can copy/paste it. A simple fix might be to uncheck "first row as names" and add the header back later.

Comment: what command did you use? read.table(), read.csv(), fread() ? did you try specifying the seperator? like: `read.table(file=..., sep=",")`

Comment: I used read_csv

Comment: Please provide a complete codein a reproducible manner  that you used in the question. Do not post it in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could skip the first line and provide the column names with the `col_names` argument to `read_csv`:

```
read_csv('kd30.csv', col_names = c("soil_moisture_12_inch", "soil_moisture_16_inch", "soil_moisture_20_inch", "pressure_switch"), skip = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [RFC4108](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#page-2), this is an invalid csv file.

> If fields are not enclosed with double quotes, then double quotes may not appear inside the fields.

I suggest you either fix the file or skip the first line of the file when reading it.